# combining "LIKE", "NOT LIKE" & "OR"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am learning MySQL and I have tried to combine "NOT LIKE" with "OR" in my queries in vain.

Assuming I have a table1 with one column called "word" as below :

```
              word
        1      SPAS
        2      SPAM
        3     HILAS
        4     BAMM
        5     ASCAR
        6      CASE
        7     ASHISPA
```

if run this code:

```
   SELECT * FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.word LIKE '%AS%' AND
                             table1.word LIKE '%SP%';
```

I get

```
       word
   1    SPAS
   7 ASHISPA
```

When I combine with "NOT LIKE " as below:

```
         SELECT * FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.word LIKE '%AS%' AND
                            table1.word LIKE '%SP%' AND
                            table1.word NOT LIKE '%HI%';
```

I get the following :

```
      word
    1 SPAS
```

When I run the query with "OR" as below :

```
  SELECT * FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.word LIKE '%AS%' or
                             table1.word LIKE '%SP%';
```

I get the results as:

```
          word
     1    SPAS
     2    SPAM
     3   HILAS
     5   ASCAR
     6    CASE
     7 ASHISPA
```

In order to omit 'HILAS' and 'ASHISPA' have tried :

```
  SELECT * FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.word LIKE '%AS%' OR
                            table1.word LIKE '%SP%' AND
                            table1.word NOT LIKE '%HI%'
```

and got :

```
         word
     1    SPAS
     2    SPAM
     3   HILAS
     5   ASCAR
     6    CASE
     7 ASHISPA
```

How can one use "OR" to query words with 'SP' and 'AS' and use "NOT LIKE" to exclude those having 'HI' and get the results below:

```
          word
     1    SPAS
     2    SPAM                
     5   ASCAR
     6    CASE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need parentheses:

```
WHERE (table1.word LIKE '%AS%' OR table1.word LIKE '%SP%') AND
      table1.word NOT LIKE '%HI%'
```

You should always use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.